# Google Data Studio iFrame bar on top of dashboard?

Tags: iframe, looker-studio

When you're embedding a Google Data Studio report with an iFrame, a navigation bar appears on the bottom of the dashboard for navigating between tabs and full-screen mode:

[image]

It states [here](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7450249?hl=en) that you can't remove this bar, but would it possible to move it to the top of the dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to change the bar in any way.

If this becomes distracting for your users, I suggest you increase your report canvas size and keep appropriate white space at the bottom so the bar does not overlap any of your dashboard elements.